# Retrieving data from an NGRX store and triggering a new action

Tags: angular, rxjs, store, ngrx

Though I have spent a lot of time in the AngularJS world and a bit in the Angular world, I'm fairly new to RXJS and NGRX and have been running into some issues. My NGRX setup is similar to the way the NGRX team recommends setting it up in their example project (https://stackblitz.com/run).

**The Situation**

I have an entity called 'site' which I have stored in my NGRX store. When I get to a specific screen I am trying to get the 'Id' of 'Site' from my store and then dispatch a new NGRX action using the Site Id as the parameter. To do this, I am trying to subscribe to a site$ observable and dispatch the action within that subscription.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as fromSite from '../../site/store/reducers/site.reducer';
import * as SiteActions from '../../site/store/actions/site.actions';
import { Site } from '../../site/site';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-grouping',
  templateUrl: './category-grouping.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-grouping.component.scss']
})
export class CategoryGroupingComponent implements OnInit {
  site$: Observable<any>;
  site: Site;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromSite.State>) {
    this.site$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromSite.getSite));
    this.site$.subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.site) {
        this.store.dispatch(new SiteActions.GetGroupsAndCategories(data.site.id));
        this.site = data.site;
      }
    });
}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**The Problem**

Dispatching the action within the subscription (once I have the site Id) breaks everything! The browser completely freezes and has to be force quit. I don't receive any console errors, but I must be doing something very wrong.

**The Question**

What is the correct way of doing this? Should I not be doing it within a subscribe? Is there a better way to get a value from the store and then use that value to dispatch another action?

Comment: prob wont fix your prob but the docs say never do this kind of heavy code in the constructor, use ngOnInit - only very lightweight code in constructor

Comment: good to know, hadn't read that.

Answer (score 3):

Look like you have recursion: dispatch `GetGroupsAndCategories` action change output of `select(fromSite.getSite)`, `site$` emit new value.

If you want to get some data before navigate to screen - use [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating)

```
@Injectable()
export class SomethingResolver implements Resolve<Action> {

  constructor (
    private store: Store<State>,
    private action$: Actions
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Action> {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: Actions.FETCH_SOMETHING });
    const responseOK = this.action$.ofType(Actions.RESPONSE_OK);
    const responseError = this.action$.ofType(Actions.RESPONSE_ERROR)
      .do(() => this.router.navigate(['']);
    return Observable.race(responseOk, responseError).take(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: so you're saying that my initial getSite action (not seen in my code) and my GetGroupsAndCategories action are both updating the site store, thus causing an infinite loop to occur?

Comment: Add `console.log` to `this.site$.subscribe`. I think it will be called pretty often.

Comment: regardless of if I'm getting the site information in the resolver or if I'm getting it in the component, I would imagine that my fromSite.getSite selector is what's causing this issue. My GetSite action and my GetGroupsAndCategories action are both updating the site store, but they are updating different properties within that store. Perhaps if I can make my GetSite selector more specific then triggering an action in the subscribe won't cause an infinite loop.

Comment: You are right. I'm glad to see that we were able to answer